# Set up an ADC ISR, but every time an ADC Interrupt is called it goes to isr_trap.asm instead

Tags: adc, interrupts, msp430

I am trying to do a program with my [MSP430FR6989](http://www.ti.com/product/MSP430FR6989) from Texas Instruments. I
send an Analogue signal to my ADC module in the uC, which converts it to a digital signal. If the value is greater than **0x800** (**1.65 V**), set a blue LED, else clear the blue LED

I am trying to do that with interrupts.

This is a snippet of my code

**EDIT2** I added the whole code instead of the snippet

```
#include <msp430.h> 


#define ENABLE_PINS 0xFFFE

void ADC_SETUP (void);

int main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // Stop watchdog timer
    PM5CTL0 = ENABLE_PINS;
    P4DIR = BIT3;

    ADC_SETUP ();

    ADC12IER0 = ADC12IE0;

    _BIS_SR(GIE);

    ADC12CTL0 = ADC12CTL0 | ADC12ENC;
    ADC12CTL0 = ADC12CTL0 | ADC12SC;

    while(1);

    return 0;
}

void ADC_SETUP (void)
{
    #define ADC12_SHT_16      0x0200
    #define ADC12_ON          0x0010
    #define ADC12_SHT_SRC_SEL 0x0200
    #define ADC12_12BIT       0x0020
    #define ADC12_P92         0x000A

    ADC12CTL0 = ADC12_SHT_16 | ADC12_ON;
    ADC12CTL1 = ADC12_SHT_SRC_SEL;
    ADC12CTL2 = ADC12_12BIT;
    ADC12MCTL0 = ADC12_P92;
}


#pragma vector = ADC12_VECTOR//0xFFEA//ADC12_VECTOR
__interrupt void ADC12_ISR (void)
{
    if(ADC12MEM0 > 0x0800)
        P4OUT = BIT3;
    else
        P4OUT = 0x00;

    ADC12CTL0 = ADC12CTL0 | ADC12SC;
}
```

when I build it, I get this warning.

> #2580-D pragma vector = accepts numeric arguments or
>   "unused_interrupt" but not ADC12_VECTOR

When I debug it, and my uC goes to **Line A** and the ADC12SC bit is set, it goes to **isr_trap.asm**, and my uC is stuck there

Kindly help me with this issue.

**Start of EDIT_0**

MSP430FR6989

Code Composer Studio 6.1.0

Compiler: TI v4.4.3

**End of EDIT_0**

**Start of EDIT_1**

I can't copy and paste the .map file here as it is too big, as I exceeded the character limit for this post.

Instead, I copied the file into a text file and sent it to this link.

https://we.tl/t-4aECqSr4yA

It is called ADC_ISR_UDEMY.map.txt

**End of EDIT_1**

**Start of EDIT_3**

Sorry for the late reply, I appreciate everyone's help in this thread.

I tried doing 3 projects, one with Timer A0 CCR0 ISR (**ISR_TRAP_TIMER_TEST**), one with ADC12_B ISR (**ISR_TRAP_ADC_TEST**), and one with ADC12_B isr with @GVelascoh Header (**ISR_TRAP_ADC_HEADER_2**).

ISR_TRAP_TIMER_TEST
worked fine, the P1.0 LED was blinking

```
#include <msp430.h> 

#define ENABLE_PINS 0xFFFE

void init_Timer (void);

int main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // Stop watchdog timer
    PM5CTL0 = ENABLE_PINS;
    P1DIR = BIT0;

    init_Timer ();

    _BIS_SR(GIE);

    while(1);

    return 0;
}

void init_Timer (void)
{
    TA0CTL = TASSEL__ACLK | MC__UP;
    TA0CCR0 = 3000;
    TA0CCTL0 = CCIE;
}

#pragma vector = TIMER0_A0_VECTOR //TA0 CCR0
__interrupt void Test_ISR (void)
{
    P1OUT = P1OUT ^ BIT0;

    //clear the flag
}
```

Build:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project ISR_TRAP_TIMER_TEST ****

"C:\\ti\\ccsv6\\utils\\bin\\gmake" -k all 
'Building file: ../main.c'
'Invoking: MSP430 Compiler'
"C:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_4.4.3/bin/cl430" -vmspx --abi=eabi --data_model=restricted --use_hw_mpy=F5 --include_path="C:/ti/ccsv6/ccs_base/msp430/include" --include_path="C:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_4.4.3/include" --advice:power=all --advice:hw_config=all -g --define=__MSP430FR6989__ --diag_warning=225 --display_error_number --diag_wrap=off --silicon_errata=CPU21 --silicon_errata=CPU22 --silicon_errata=CPU40 --printf_support=minimal --preproc_with_compile --preproc_dependency="main.pp"  "../main.c"
"../main.c", line 19: warning #112-D: statement is unreachable
"../main.c", line 17: remark #1527-D: (ULP 2.1) Detected SW delay loop using empty loop. Recommend using a timer module instead
'Finished building: ../main.c'
' '
'Building target: ISR_TRAP_TIMER_TEST.out'
'Invoking: MSP430 Linker'
"C:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_4.4.3/bin/cl430" -vmspx --abi=eabi --data_model=restricted --use_hw_mpy=F5 --advice:power=all --advice:hw_config=all -g --define=__MSP430FR6989__ --diag_warning=225 --display_error_number --diag_wrap=off --silicon_errata=CPU21 --silicon_errata=CPU22 --silicon_errata=CPU40 --printf_support=minimal -z -m"ISR_TRAP_TIMER_TEST.map" --heap_size=160 --stack_size=160 --cinit_hold_wdt=on -i"C:/ti/ccsv6/ccs_base/msp430/include" -i"C:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_4.4.3/lib" -i"C:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_4.4.3/include" -i"C:/ti/ccsv6/ccs_base/msp430/lib/5xx_6xx_FRxx" -i"C:/ti/ccsv6/ccs_base/msp430/lib/FR59xx" --reread_libs --priority --warn_sections --display_error_number --diag_wrap=off --xml_link_info="ISR_TRAP_TIMER_TEST_linkInfo.xml" --use_hw_mpy=F5 --rom_model -o "ISR_TRAP_TIMER_TEST.out" "./main.obj" "../lnk_msp430fr6989.cmd"  -l"libmath.a" -l"libc.a" 
<Linking>
remark #10372-D: (ULP 4.1) Detected uninitialized Port A in this project. Recommend initializing all unused ports to eliminate wasted current consumption on unused pins.
remark #10372-D: (ULP 4.1) Detected uninitialized Port B in this project. Recommend initializing all unused ports to eliminate wasted current consumption on unused pins.
remark #10372-D: (ULP 4.1) Detected uninitialized Port C in this project. Recommend initializing all unused ports to eliminate wasted current consumption on unused pins.
remark #10372-D: (ULP 4.1) Detected uninitialized Port D in this project. Recommend initializing all unused ports to eliminate wasted current consumption on unused pins.
remark #10372-D: (ULP 4.1) Detected uninitialized Port E in this project. Recommend initializing all unused ports to eliminate wasted current consumption on unused pins.
'Finished building target: ISR_TRAP_TIMER_TEST.out'
' '

**** Build Finished ****
```

ISR_TRAP_ADC_TEST
The uC still goes to the isr_trap.asm

```
#include <msp430.h> 

#define ENABLE_PINS 0xFFFE

void init_ADC (void);

int main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // Stop watchdog timer
    PM5CTL0 = ENABLE_PINS;
    P1DIR = BIT0;

    init_ADC ();

    _BIS_SR(GIE);

    ADC12CTL0 = ADC12CTL0 | ADC12ENC;
    ADC12CTL0 = ADC12CTL0 | ADC12SC;

    while(1);

    return 0;
}

void init_ADC (void)
{
    ADC12CTL0 = ADC12ON | ADC12SHT0_2;
    ADC12CTL1 = ADC12SHP;
    ADC12CTL2 = ADC12RES__12BIT;
    ADC12MCTL0 = ADC12INCH_10;

    ADC12IER0 = ADC12IE0;
}

#pragma vector = ADC12_VECTOR
__interrupt void ADC12_ISR (void)
{
    if(ADC12MEM0 > 0x0800)
        P1OUT = BIT0;
    else
        P1OUT = 0x00;
}
```

Build:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project ISR_TRAP_ADC_TEST ****

"C:\\ti\\ccsv6\\utils\\bin\\gmake" -k all 
'Building file: ../main.c'
'Invoking: MSP430 Compiler'
"C:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_4.4.3/bin/cl430" -vmspx --abi=eabi --data_model=restricted --use_hw_mpy=F5 --include_path="C:/ti/ccsv6/ccs_base/msp430/include" --include_path="C:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_4.4.3/include" --advice:power=all --advice:hw_config=all -g --define=__MSP430FR6989__ --diag_warning=225 --display_error_number --diag_wrap=off --silicon_errata=CPU21 --silicon_errata=CPU22 --silicon_errata=CPU40 --printf_support=minimal --preproc_with_compile --preproc_dependency="main.pp"  "../main.c"
"../main.c", line 22: warning #112-D: statement is unreachable
"../main.c", line 20: remark #1527-D: (ULP 2.1) Detected SW delay loop using empty loop. Recommend using a timer module instead
"../main.c", line 35: warning #2580-D: pragma vector= accepts numeric arguments or "unused_interrupts" but not ADC12_VECTOR
'Finished building: ../main.c'
' '
'Building target: ISR_TRAP_ADC_TEST.out'
'Invoking: MSP430 Linker'
"C:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_4.4.3/bin/cl430" -vmspx --abi=eabi --data_model=restricted --use_hw_mpy=F5 --advice:power=all --advice:hw_config=all -g --define=__MSP430FR6989__ --diag_warning=225 --display_error_number --diag_wrap=off --silicon_errata=CPU21 --silicon_errata=CPU22 --silicon_errata=CPU40 --printf_support=minimal -z -m"ISR_TRAP_ADC_TEST.map" --heap_size=160 --stack_size=160 --cinit_hold_wdt=on -i"C:/ti/ccsv6/ccs_base/msp430/include" -i"C:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_4.4.3/lib" -i"C:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_4.4.3/include" -i"C:/ti/ccsv6/ccs_base/msp430/lib/5xx_6xx_FRxx" -i"C:/ti/ccsv6/ccs_base/msp430/lib/FR59xx" --reread_libs --priority --warn_sections --display_error_number --diag_wrap=off --xml_link_info="ISR_TRAP_ADC_TEST_linkInfo.xml" --use_hw_mpy=F5 --rom_model -o "ISR_TRAP_ADC_TEST.out" "./main.obj" "../lnk_msp430fr6989.cmd"  -l"libmath.a" -l"libc.a" 
<Linking>
remark #10372-D: (ULP 4.1) Detected uninitialized Port A in this project. Recommend initializing all unused ports to eliminate wasted current consumption on unused pins.
remark #10372-D: (ULP 4.1) Detected uninitialized Port B in this project. Recommend initializing all unused ports to eliminate wasted current consumption on unused pins.
remark #10372-D: (ULP 4.1) Detected uninitialized Port C in this project. Recommend initializing all unused ports to eliminate wasted current consumption on unused pins.
remark #10372-D: (ULP 4.1) Detected uninitialized Port D in this project. Recommend initializing all unused ports to eliminate wasted current consumption on unused pins.
remark #10372-D: (ULP 4.1) Detected uninitialized Port E in this project. Recommend initializing all unused ports to eliminate wasted current consumption on unused pins.
'Finished building target: ISR_TRAP_ADC_TEST.out'
' '

**** Build Finished ****
```

ISR_TRAP_ADC_HEADER_2
I still got the same issue, where the uC goes to isr_trap.asm (I hope I added your header right @GVelascoh)

```
#include <msp430.h> 


#define ENABLE_PINS 0xFFFE

void init_ADC (void);

int main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // Stop watchdog timer
    PM5CTL0 = ENABLE_PINS;
    P1DIR = BIT0;

    init_ADC ();

    _BIS_SR(GIE);

    ADC12CTL0 = ADC12CTL0 | ADC12ENC;
    ADC12CTL0 = ADC12CTL0 | ADC12SC;

    while(1);

    return 0;
}

void init_ADC (void)
{
    ADC12CTL0 = ADC12ON | ADC12SHT0_2;
    ADC12CTL1 = ADC12SHP;
    ADC12CTL2 = ADC12RES__12BIT;
    ADC12MCTL0 = ADC12INCH_10;

    ADC12IER0 = ADC12IE0;
}

#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector = ADC12_VECTOR
__interrupt void ADC12_ISR(void)
{
    if(ADC12MEM0 > 0x0800)
        P1OUT = BIT0;
    else
        P1OUT = 0x00;
}
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
void __attribute__ ((interrupt(ADC12_VECTOR))) ADC12_ISR (void)
#else
#error Compiler not supported!
#endif
```

Build:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project ISR_TRAP_ADC_HEADER_2 ****

"C:\\ti\\ccsv6\\utils\\bin\\gmake" -k all 
'Building file: ../main.c'
'Invoking: MSP430 Compiler'
"C:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_4.4.3/bin/cl430" -vmspx --abi=eabi --data_model=restricted --use_hw_mpy=F5 --include_path="C:/ti/ccsv6/ccs_base/msp430/include" --include_path="C:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_4.4.3/include" --advice:power=all --advice:hw_config=all -g --define=__MSP430FR6989__ --diag_warning=225 --display_error_number --diag_wrap=off --silicon_errata=CPU21 --silicon_errata=CPU22 --silicon_errata=CPU40 --printf_support=minimal --preproc_with_compile --preproc_dependency="main.pp"  "../main.c"
"../main.c", line 23: warning #112-D: statement is unreachable
"../main.c", line 21: remark #1527-D: (ULP 2.1) Detected SW delay loop using empty loop. Recommend using a timer module instead
"../main.c", line 37: warning #2580-D: pragma vector= accepts numeric arguments or "unused_interrupts" but not ADC12_VECTOR
'Finished building: ../main.c'
' '
'Building target: ISR_TRAP_ADC_HEADER_2.out'
'Invoking: MSP430 Linker'
"C:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_4.4.3/bin/cl430" -vmspx --abi=eabi --data_model=restricted --use_hw_mpy=F5 --advice:power=all --advice:hw_config=all -g --define=__MSP430FR6989__ --diag_warning=225 --display_error_number --diag_wrap=off --silicon_errata=CPU21 --silicon_errata=CPU22 --silicon_errata=CPU40 --printf_support=minimal -z -m"ISR_TRAP_ADC_HEADER_2.map" --heap_size=160 --stack_size=160 --cinit_hold_wdt=on -i"C:/ti/ccsv6/ccs_base/msp430/include" -i"C:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_4.4.3/lib" -i"C:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_4.4.3/include" -i"C:/ti/ccsv6/ccs_base/msp430/lib/5xx_6xx_FRxx" -i"C:/ti/ccsv6/ccs_base/msp430/lib/FR59xx" --reread_libs --priority --warn_sections --display_error_number --diag_wrap=off --xml_link_info="ISR_TRAP_ADC_HEADER_2_linkInfo.xml" --use_hw_mpy=F5 --rom_model -o "ISR_TRAP_ADC_HEADER_2.out" "./main.obj" "../lnk_msp430fr6989.cmd"  -l"libmath.a" -l"libc.a" 
<Linking>
remark #10372-D: (ULP 4.1) Detected uninitialized Port A in this project. Recommend initializing all unused ports to eliminate wasted current consumption on unused pins.
remark #10372-D: (ULP 4.1) Detected uninitialized Port B in this project. Recommend initializing all unused ports to eliminate wasted current consumption on unused pins.
remark #10372-D: (ULP 4.1) Detected uninitialized Port C in this project. Recommend initializing all unused ports to eliminate wasted current consumption on unused pins.
remark #10372-D: (ULP 4.1) Detected uninitialized Port D in this project. Recommend initializing all unused ports to eliminate wasted current consumption on unused pins.
remark #10372-D: (ULP 4.1) Detected uninitialized Port E in this project. Recommend initializing all unused ports to eliminate wasted current consumption on unused pins.
'Finished building target: ISR_TRAP_ADC_HEADER_2.out'
' '

**** Build Finished ****
```

**End of EDIT_3**

**Start of EDIT_4**

Thank you for your help, I fixed my problem, I uninstalled CCS v6.1.0 and installed CCS 8.2.0, written the same program, and the problem is gone.

Thought I would share this, so I won't leave it hanging.

**End of EDIT_4**

Comment: Looks more like you uC doesn't know where to jump when ADC interrupt arrives, hence it panics. You have to tell your Interrupt controller to jump @ ADC12_Vector. Are you sure you are doing that?

Comment: it only does that for ADC interrupt, not for the Timer0_A0 ISR for example. How do I fix it

Comment: As far as I know, yes, I enabled ADC12 MEM0 interrupt, global interrupt, and when the value at ADC12MEM0 changes (conversion finished) it will jump to the ISR

Comment: Well the warning seems to tell the story. ADC12_VECTOR seems to be unresolveable to a numeric value which the compiler expects. Are you sure you are using the correct symbol?

Comment: What CPU is the compiler configured for?

Comment: @Arsenal yes, that is the correct symbol, I even replaced the symbol with the hex number, the warning is gone, but the uC still goes to the isr_trap.asm

Comment: @CL I don't follow, if you mean the laptop I am using, it is Dell Inspiron 15

Comment: What compiler are you using to compile that program? How is it configured?

Comment: @CL It is TI v4.4.3 and it was configured as Debug

Comment: @CL refers to the compiler, if you go to project>properties>general you will see compiler options, you could be using either TI compiler or gcc. I will put a possible fix as an answer if this is the case

Comment: @GVelascoh I opened it and at the general tab/Advanced setting it mentions compiler version: TI v4.4.3 (Texas Instrument compiler)

Comment: Could you post your .map file?

Comment: @GVelascoh I will post it on **EDIT_1**

Comment: @GVelascoh, It was too big to add in the post, so I added a link to it, I hope that's okay

Comment: Please add the following three lines: `#if !defined (__MSP430FR5989__)`     `#error __MSP430FR5989__ is not defined`     `#endif`     Do you get an error?

Answer (score 1):

From your map file, it seems like your ISR function is not compiled as there is no code associated with it. In the "section allocation map" you can find that there is no reference to the symbol `ADC12_ISR`

```
.text:_isr 
*          0    00004400    00000020     
                00004400    0000001a     rts430x_lc_rd_eabi.lib : boot_special.obj (.text:_isr:_c_int00_noargs_noexit)
                0000441a    00000006                            : isr_trap.obj (.text:_isr:__TI_ISR_TRAP)
```

This is a part of a map file for another project I have, see how ISR symbols are detailed in it:

```
.text      0    0000c600    00000d30     
                0000c600    0000023c     main.obj (.text:main)
                   ...
                0000cc62    0000007e     my-lib-Debug_2.lib : events.obj (.text:events_insert)
                0000cce0    0000007c                            : i2c_master.obj (.text:_isr:USCIB0_ISR)
                0000ce30    0000005e     port_interrupts.obj (.text:_isr:Port3_ISR)
                   ...
```

Try cleaning your project and rebuild it again. Also, which files are you including, as the code you posted is not compilable as it is. Also, from the map file, I see you have another function, ADC_SETUP.

**Edit:** I just see that in your code you are not turning off the watchdog, which is enabled at start. Usually, this line is added at the beginning of the  main function to do so: `WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;`

---

If your problem is due to compiler, this preprocessor conditionals will help you:

```
#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector = ADC12_VECTOR
__interrupt void ADC12_ISR(void)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
void __attribute__ ((interrupt(ADC12_VECTOR))) ADC12_ISR (void)
#else
#error Compiler not supported!
#endif
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, when I posted I tried to just add a snippet of the code, not the whole real code, as I was trying to put relevant stuff of my code in this thread. ADC_SETUP is the same as init_ADC. I will change init_ADC to ADC_SETUP, and put the whole code (for reference).I did disable WDT, but I didn't think it was relevant to the post, so I didn't add it in my code, I just replaced it with //code

Comment: I replaced the snippet of my code with the real code I am using

Comment: I searched online for isr_trap.asm, and there are several links from TI forums that says that I isr_trap happens if I did not clear the interrupt flag, which I checked it was cleared, or enabled 2 Interrupts but there is only one ISR function, and the 2nd ISR is called the uC doesn't know wherer to go, which I also checked there is only one interrupt enabled (ADC12IE0)

Comment: isr_trap.asm somehow a trap/breakpoint for my debugger if the uC felt there is something wrong with my interrupt, I will try again with 2 diff projects one for ADC ISR and the other of a Timer ISR and see how it goes

Comment: Actually `ISR_trap()` is the default function for processing interrupts, this is, in case you enable an interrupt but do not define a ISR (or forget to), `ISR_trap()` will process it. By default, all interrupt vectors points to that function.

Comment: As @CL asked in the comments, check that the device in the project properties is the one you are using (MSP430FR6989) and that the linker file matches the device. In addition, you can post all warning messages you get from the build, that could be helpful as well.

Comment: @GVeloscoh well I use CCS wizard to create a project, and leave the job of compiling/building, and linking to CCS, I thought if there were no issues with the linker files of the timer isr project, then there shouldn't be a problem with the ADC isr project. Besides in the build of my ISR_TRAP_ADC_TEST, it mentions `'Building target: ISR_TRAP_ADC_HEADER_2.out'
'Invoking: MSP430 Linker'`is that sufficient or I should do something else

Comment: Could you attach your linker file, please? I tried your code in CCS online and it does not generate the #pragma warning, and is using a newer version of the compiler.

Comment: I am a bit of a beginner in microcontrollers, how do I get the linker files of my project, (PS my CCS is Code Composer Studio 6.1.0)

Comment: My project is called ISR_TRAP_ADC_TEST, when I created a project CCS created a folder named it ISR_TRAP_ADC_TEST

ISR_TRAP_ADC_TEST/Debug/ISR_TRAP_ADC_TEST.out

Is the .out file the linker file you want, if so I have put it in this link

https://we.tl/t-8hECUpt9i1

Comment: If you look at your project directory, you will find a .cmd file, like `lnk_msp430fr6989.cmd`, that is the linker file. btw, why are you using old versions of TI tools,? CCS latest is v8 and TI compiler even changed its versioning syntax

Comment: This is the link to the linker (.cmd file)
https://we.tl/t-RY9YecOvmJ

I am doing a Udemy course for microcontrollers, and the course suggested that I use CCS version 6, so the student and the lecturer can be on the same page if there were any questions regarding his tutorials. I will update the version when I finish the course or if it resolves this issue

Comment: Try updating your compiler, I think last version of TI 4.4.x is 4.4.8. I could not find major differences with the last version of linker file, here it is, though [linkerfile v1.206](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gustavovelascoh/e5f646a49943b50da79594e07e98aea5/raw/ac0e54bd3d44f0d104844a5fbad4a60e825be35f/lnk_msp430fr6989.cmd). You can also check where the function isr_trap is implemented and previous to it there should be the list of all interrupt vector. You can compare how is the syntax there.

Comment: I uninstalled CCS 6.1.0 and installed CCS 8.2.0, and the problem was gone. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You must tell the compiler which microcontroller you are using. This is asked when creating a project, but can be changed later with **Project → Properties → General → Device → Variant**.

Comment: I did that, Variant: MSP430FRxxx